# Get count of distinct values in a column grouped by date mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to run a mongodb query that for each day requested it will return the count of unique values in a different column. For instance for the month of june the query will return the date as well as the count of distinct values were in the b column on the date. Any one know how to do this I have tried a couple different things with no luck

Below are a couple sample documents, as well as what the output should be

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("578fa05a7391bb0d34bd3c28"),
  "IP" : "123.123.123.123",
  "datetime" : ISODate("2016-07-20T10:04:56-05:00")
},
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("578fa05a7391bb0d34bd3c28"),
  "IP" : "110.123.1.2",
  "datetime" : ISODate("2016-07-20T10:04:56-05:00"),
}
```

Output should be

```
{
"date":"2016-07-20",
count:2 -- this is distinct number of IPs for the date above
}
```

Comment: Please show sample documents and a desired result

Comment: I have edited the question to have this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With an `aggregate`, you can do :

- 2 `$project`
- 2 `$group`

The 2 projects are used to split day-month-year into a new field to group by it in the `$group`

mongo query is :

```
 db.device.aggregate([{
    $project: {
        _id: 1,
        IP: 1,
        day: {
            "$dayOfMonth": "$datetime"
        },
        month: {
            "$month": "$datetime"
        },
        year: {
            "$year": "$datetime"
        }
    }
 }, {
    $project: {
        _id: 1,
        IP: 1,
        datetime: {
            $concat: [{
                    $substr: ["$year", 0, 4]
                },
                "-", {
                    $substr: ["$month", 0, 2]
                },
                "-", {
                    $substr: ["$day", 0, 2]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
 }, {
    $group: {
        _id: {
            date: "$datetime",
            IP: "$IP"
        }
    }
 }, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$_id.date",
        count: {
            $sum: 1
        }
    }
 }])
```

`$sum:1` is used to count your fields

It will give you something like this :

```
{ "_id" : "2016-7-20", "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "2016-8-20", "count" : 1 }
```

for the input data :

```
> db.device.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("578fa05a7391bb0d34bd3c28"), "IP" : "123.123.123.123", "datetime" : ISODate("2016-07-20T15:04:56Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("578fa05a7391bb0d34bd3c29"), "IP" : "110.123.1.2", "datetime" : ISODate("2016-07-20T15:04:56Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("578fa05a7391bb0d34bd3c25"), "IP" : "110.123.1.2", "datetime" : ISODate("2016-07-20T15:04:56Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("578fa05a7391bb0d34bd3c30"), "IP" : "110.123.1.2", "datetime" : ISODate("2016-08-20T15:04:56Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("578fa05a7391bb0d34bd3c12"), "IP" : "110.123.1.2", "datetime" : ISODate("2016-08-20T15:04:56Z") }
```

Comment: Actually hold on, you just get the count of all the documents I want the count to be the count of distinct IPs for that date

Comment: I want it grouped so that in your answer for instance the date 2016-7-20 the count should be 2, because there are 2 distinct IPs on that day

Comment: so for instance, the query below returns the count of distinct IPs for June 2,2016 , I want a an aggregate that can compute this for each date range specified
`db.collection.distinct("IP",{datetime:{$gte:ISODate('2016-06-02'),$lt:ISODate('2016-06-03')}}).length`

Comment: Ok, I've updated my post. One additional `$group` is necessary for this